# React and Material-UI: how to structure application with multiple pages

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, meteor-react

I'm using Meteor, React and Material-UI to create an app. To keep it simple, let's say that the app has two pages: home and user.

Both pages should have the same layout: an AppBar with a hamburger menu on the left and an IconMenu on the right. When the hamburger menu is selected a Drawer will slide out from the left, and when the right menu is selected a drop-down menu will appear.

For my purposes the drawer menu is static, i.e. the menu entries don't change depending on what page (home or user) is being displayed. The drop-down menu on the right, however, will change depending on what page is active, i.e. it's context-sensitive.

My question is: what options do I have in terms of building this?

I think one option is to create two page components, e.g. HomePage and UserPage, and compose each using e.g. MyAppBar and MyDrawer, plus whatever content the specific page should contain. Each page would then be responsible for creating the menu items on the drop-down menu and passing them to MyAppBar and then the entire page would be rendered.

I believe this would solve the problem, but I'm not sure if there is a better way. For instance, is there a second approach where I could update just the content component of the page and have the owning component (e.g. an ApplicationPage component) query the content component (e.g. HomeContent or UserContent) for the entries of the drop-down menu and set the drop-down menu when there's a content component change? Any other options?

I'm using React Router to do routing for /home and /user so the above must also fit in with that.

Answer (score 0):

I use react router for this purpose.

```
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
     <Route component={App}>
         <Route path='/login/' components={{main: Login}} />
         <Route path='/confirm' 
                components={{
                                main: Confirm,
                                sidebar:Sidebar
                            }} 
          />
     </Route>
  </Router>
```

In the Template App, we can then use this.props.main and this.props.sidebar as variables.

Please look at https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/sidebar/app.js form more details.